# How to update EXIF tags of a picture file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, picturebox, jpeg, exif

Title says everything.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using MiniExiftool, a ruby interface to Perl's Exiftool.

- https://github.com/janfri/mini_exiftool
- [http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/%7Ephil/exiftool/)

Usage:

```rb
exif = MiniExiftool.new(file_path)
exif.date_time_original = Time.now
exif["captionextract"] = "This is my new caption"
exif.save
```

There is also: https://github.com/janfri/multi_exiftool

Comment: I've had success editing existing tags but is there a way to add new ones?

Comment: exif["whatever"] = "Foo"

Comment: if you are looking for just a reader, there is https://github.com/exiftool-rb/exiftool.rb

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [exifr](https://rubygems.org/gems/exifr)?

> EXIF Reader is a module to read EXIF from JPEG and TIFF images.

Comment: Yes I did. It can only read tags but there isn't any writing support.

I'm now using a call to the "jhead" tool.

Comment: "exifr" stands for "exif reader" and you didn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try ruby-libexif: http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/ruby-libexif/

Usage: http://74.125.113.132/search?q=cache:yjOeG4UnD38J:tach.arege.net/trac/browser/debian/libexif-ruby/trunk/exif.rd.en%3Frev%3D51%26format%3Draw+ruby+set+exif+tag&cd=10&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a

Comment: Thanks,
I had seen this projet but it seems to be dead, all links are broken so I'm unable to install it...

Comment: Oh, that sucks. I'll go ahead and be blasphemous then. Try this: http://tilloy.net/dev/pyexiv2/